# Python regex finding words separated with other words

Tags: python, regex, findall

Is there a way to use `re.findall` or another regex method to count the number of occurrences of words in a specified order, separated by an arbitrary number of words?

Here is a "brute force" implementation:

```
def search_query(query, page):
    count=i=0
    for word in page.split():
            if word == query[i]: i+=1
            if i==len(query): 
                count+=1
                break
    print count

search_query(['hello','kilojoules'],'hello my good friend kilojoules')
1
```

for example, when the query is `hello kilojoules`, I would like to recognize `hello my good friend kilojoules` as an instance of my query, but for `kilojoules is my good friend` not to be counted.

Here is my naive attempt at a satisfactory regex: `re.findall('hello\s\Skilojoules','hello my friend kilojoules')`. This doesn't work. I thought it would work because my understanding of what this says is "find all instances of `hello` and `kilojoules` separated by white space or blank space".

Comment: Maybe `(?s)\bhello\b.*?\bkilojoules\b`? Note that `\s\S` is just a whitespace followed with a non-whitespace. `hello\s\Skilojoules` can match `hello bkilojoules`, but not `hello kilojoules`.

Comment: generic mumble about using [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) here, unless you love typing the backslash button for whatever reason,

Comment: @stribizhev `re.findall('(?s)\bhello\b.*?\bkilojoules\b','hello my amigo kilojoules')` returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify:

```
(?s)\bhello\b.*?\bkilojoules\b
```

This regex means *match a whole word **hello**, then any character even a whitespace and linebreak, and then a whole word **kilojoules**.

If you do not have linebreaks, and if you do not care about whole word match, use

```
hello.*?kilojoules
```

Note that `\s\S` is just a whitespace followed with a non-whitespace. Thus, `hello\s\Skilojoules` can match `hello bkilojoules`, but not `hello kilojoules`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found success in `re.findall('hello.*?kilojoules','a happy hello my amigo kilojoules now goodbye')`, following stribizhev's advice